# How Flower determines Celery workers?

Tags: celery, flower

Celery workers are being ran like this:

```
celery -A backend worker --broker=$REDIS_URL
```

Flower:

```
celery -A backend flower --broker=$REDIS_URL
```

When one run another worker Flower determines it. But how? Is there information stored about workers in Redis for example?

Answer (score 1):

When Flower starts, it subscribes itself to be notified of most (if not all) task and worker events ( https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#event-reference ). When you run a new Celery worker, the moment it connects to the broker Flower will receive a new `worker-online` event. - That is how it finds out there is a "new worker in town"...

Comment: @DejanlLekic is you answer imply that in a docker compose file,  a Flower container can be earlier start than a Worker container if Broker (like Redis) is the first in the line?

Comment: If it starts after, it may miss some events.